# Не работает eel в python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Пытаюсь подключить Python к HTML с помощью eel.Всё сделал правильно, и по уроку , и по документации.Но когда запускаю приложение,написано что Сайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение.

**Python**

```
import eel


eel.init("static")

@eel.expose
def say_hello_from_js(x):
    print(f"Hello from {x}")

eel.say_hello_from_python("Python!")

eel.start("index.html", size=(500, 500))
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Eello World!</h1>
    <p>Congrats, Eel seems to work fine</p>

    <script src="/eel.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
eel.say_hello_from_js("Javascript!");

eel.expose(say_hello_from_python)
function say_hello_from_python(x){
    console.log("Hello from {}".replace("{}", x))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой (мне помогло)

В `eel.start()` передайте значение host, port, mode.

1. host - строка, указывающая, какое имя хоста использовать для сервера.
2. port - указывает, какой порт использовать для сервера. Используйте 0 для автоматического выбора порта. По умолчанию: 8000. Попробуйте изменить на 8080.
3. mode - строка, указывающая, какой браузер использовать ('chrome', 'electron', 'edge', 'custom') По умолчанию: 'chrome'.

Более подробно написано тут:
https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel